# Can I use custom html-css-js form within an Email?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, gmail

I need to insert my own form in a gmail email, so that my client can fill that form, press a submit button and trigger a response with the form content to my domain. 
I already did the template (example image below) and successfully sent the email with it using python gmail API by inserting the html code in the body. My question is the following: Once the user completes the form, how do I get the info in my domain server? Maybe by doing an ajax request when the button is pressed?

Help will be much appreciated!

Thank you!!

Template example:
[image]

Comment: Most e-mail clients block JavaScript for security reasons. You should be able to send it as a regular `POST` request though (e.g., `<form action="some_script_on_your_server.php" method="POST">`).

Answer (score 0):

All javascript code is blocked by Gmail for security reasons. It would probably work with `<form action="https://external-domain.com">` but I don't think so that's a good practice. Probably sending user to your page with the accually form by `a` tag is a better call.